# I am trying to play music using tkinter and module mp3 play but it says theres no module named mp3 play(module downloaded)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, mp3

Although I have downloaded the module `mp3play` and saved it in python folder.

```
from Tkinter import *
import mp3play

root = Tk() # create tkinter window

f = mp3play.load('OnOurWay.mp3'); play = lambda: f.play()
button = Button(root, text = 'Play', command = play)

button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I got this error message:

```
Error:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:/ON F/Tkinter programs/mujic.py", line 2, in <module>
   import mp3play
   ImportError: No module named mp3play
```

Comment: how did you install it? On which platform?

Comment: You cant just download a module and place it in python folder. You need to install it. luckily, mp3play can be installed with pip: `pip install mp3play`

Comment: Stevo Mitric, i did install it from that site .

Comment: Billal BEGUERADJ, I installed it directly from the site on destop windows 7

Comment: i got it guys thank you i used pygame and tkinter together